# Given certain set of symmetries of a tensor, how do you associate the corresponding young tableaux

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

I have a particular problem, the following.

$T^{a_1 \dots a_p;b_1 \dots b_p}$ is a tensor with the following symmetries.

1) $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are completely antisymmetric, ie restricted to either$a_i's $ or $ b_i's$

2) Total interchange of $a_i$'s with $b_i$'s are symmetric, that is
$T^{a_1 \dots a_p;b_1 \dots b_p} = T^{b_1 \dots b_p;a_1 \dots a_p}$

Is this an irreducible representation of the full $S_{2p}$ group? if not how to decompose it? And what are/is the associated young tableau.

In general I would be grateful if anyone can provide me with a reference on how to go about finding the associated tableau given arbitrary symmetries, such as cyclic symmetry etc..

I am guessing the usual procedure of the Littlewood-Richardson rule can be constrained further when additional symmetries are present?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Can you make your symmetry problem more precise? Can you express it in terms of Sym and $\bigwedge$ or as a quotient of a tensor power?

Comment: Not too sure of notation mathematicians use. Is this notation clear for you?  $T \in Sym^2 1^p$. Here $1^p$ corresponds to young diagram with 1 column and p boxes,ie antisymmetric rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are describing is strongly related the "plethysm" problem.

$\mathbb S_\lambda(V)$ denotes the Schur functor. We find that the irreducible polynomial representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ are $\mathbb S_\lambda(\mathbb C^k)$ (with $\lambda$ having at most $k$ rows). The question is how does
$$\mathbb S_\lambda(\mathbb S_\mu(\mathbb C^k))$$
split into irreducibles. This problem is in general hard and still open. I do not know about the progress on your very concrete and probably relatively easy problem, that is how does
$$\mathbb S_{2^1}(\mathbb S_{1^p}(V))$$
split into irreducible.

I don't know about many references but googling "plethysm" should help. I learned about the concept in Fulton-Harris: Representation theory p.82 Exercise 6.17.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that exactly is my problem. Naively I thought since it is symmetric under pair wise interchange. The only possibilities are $T = 2^p + 1^{2p}$. Is this correct if not can you give me a counter example. thanks again @Peter Patzt